# R: Too big legends in a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have this plot that looks awful because the legends on the left and right and bottom are too big. I tried to make them smaller with `legend.title = element_text(size=7)`, but I managed to do it only to the right side's "Answer" legend. I want all the text in the figure as the same size (7) "Answer" is.

Apparently I put that code to wrong places. I get the error of unused argument: `Error in scale_y_continuous(name = "Percentage", breaks = seq(from = 0,  :  unused argument (legend.title = element_text(size = 7))`. So where to insert that code, or do I need another code?

[image]

```
mydata %>%
  
  mutate(
    variable = recode(
      variable,
      'item3' = '
      Very long item name here')) %>%
  
  drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = variable)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = value),
           position = 'fill',
           width = 0.30)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Percentage',
                     breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.2),
                     minor_breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1),
                     labels = seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 20),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab( element_blank() ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(fioh_colors$fioh_blue_40,
               fioh_colors$fioh_blue_60,
               fioh_colors$fioh_blue_80,
               fioh_colors$fioh_blue_100,
               fioh_colors$fioh_turq_20
    ),
    labels = c(
      'yes',
      'no',
      'maybe'
    ),
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(title = 'Answer')
  ) + theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
            legend.title = element_text(size=7),
            plot.margin = margin(t = 30, r =  30, b = 20, l = 0),
            axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
            axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
            panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'lightgrey'),
            axis.text.y = element_text(
              size = 11,
              face = 'bold',
              hjust = 0
            )) +
  coord_flip()
```

Data

````
structure(list(variable = c("item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item3", 
"item3", "item3", "item3"), value = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -147L))```
````

Comment: You can adjust the text side here: `axis.text.y = element_text( size = 11, face = 'bold', hjust = 0)` also consider adding line breaks `\n` to the axis label to break the line into multiple ones.